# Still cannot open display :0

Tags: ssh, display

I'm trying to run `chromium-browser` on my raspberry pi remotely through SSH.

I want `chromium-browser` to use **the display of the raspberry pi** (**not** the local display of my Windows machine).

Even when I run

```
arthur@raspberrypi:~ $ export DISPLAY=:0.0
arthur@raspberrypi:~ $ chromium-browser
```

or

```
arthur@raspberrypi:~ $ export DISPLAY=:0
arthur@raspberrypi:~ $ chromium-browser
```

I still get the same error :

```
(chromium-browser:1330): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I'm using Putty, X11 forwarding is disabled both in `sshd_config` and Putty settings.

This is meant to be a **one-shot** run. I do not want to control anything remotely after the browser is started. The ultimate goal is to be able to run chromium with an URL as parameter, so the page displays on the HDMI the raspberry is hooked up to. That's basically it, I don't want to control anything further than that.

Is there anything else I can try to launch chromium on the remote display ?

Comment: `X11 forwarding is disabled` there's one problem, it needs to be ENABLED to work ... the other is, do you have an X server on the PC?

Comment: Ooooh okay, I thought X11 forward was meant to work the opposite way. Will try with X11 enabled. Though, why is it necessary to have some other component on the PC (you mention an X server) ? Why isn't the TTY clever enough to understand that a command should launch a GUI program on a given display ?

Comment: Everything is supposed to be ran remotely, why is it necessary to add a GUI handler on the terminal side ?

Comment: because `X11` is a protocol - you have to have something on the PC that talks `X11` - I'm assuming the PC isn't running Linux

Comment: you could just use vnc instead though - then you don't even have to `ssh`

Comment: I do not want to use VNC because I would like those commands to be ran through a bash script. And that X11 protocol thing means that if I terminate the ssh session, the GUI will also probably stop, which sucks. Will have to investigate far more than I thought on this one

Comment: BTW I think I was right with X11 forwarding disabled. X11 forwarding refers to [the mechanism that allows a user to start up remote applications but forward the application display to your local Windows machine.](https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/11035-how-to-use-x11-forwarding.html). I specifically said **I do not want to do that**. I want the display to be done **on the raspberry pi**

Comment: Oh Sorry. I misread your question.

Comment: Does *xterm* produce the same error as Chromium?

Comment: What am I supposed to do with xterm ?

Comment: I think @Janka was suggesting you replace `chromium-browser` with `xterm` as your command. This will show if the problem is Chromium specific or with the X11 setup. I'd suggest trying setting the variable in-line with the command (i.e. `DISPLAY=:0 xterm &`) as well.

Comment: Yes, the same error pops up : `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0`. I tried with the inline variable as you suggested @RogerJones

Comment: OK, so it's an X11 problem. Is the GUI/X11 actually running? Also, I notice in your question you're logged in as `arthur`, have you tried the command as `pi`?

Comment: Oh my, that fixed it ... I had to `su pi` before launching the command. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem lies somewhere between the setup of X on the Pi and adding a new user to the Pi. The new user does not seem to have full access to the X server so can't launch GUI applications from the command line but can use `su` to login as the `pi` user and run the desired applications.

Not exactly an answer but more of a workaround, I'm afraid.

If the Pi is set up to auto-login as `pi` and launch straight to the desktop then I think the `pi` user's X client (the window manager?) has exclusive access to the display so it would make sense that a second user logging in would be unable to use the same display. If this is the case you could try logging `pi` out of the desktop on the physical Pi and then running your command from the command line as the second user.

Answer (score 0):

After desktop login, the `xset` command works and does not throw

```sh
No protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0"
```